# How to Send mail to contact of associated Account through wrapper Class

Tags: apex, visualforce

My Visualforce page--

```
<apex:page controller="WrapperAcccountWithEachContact" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
 <style> 
     .Processing{
         position: fixed;
         background: url('/img/loading32.gif');
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: center;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         z-index: 10004;
         left: 0%;
         top: 0%;

     }
    </style>
  <apex:form >
  <apex:actionStatus id="status" startStyleClass="Processing"></apex:actionStatus>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Requirement Send Email on Contact from Account Seletion"  >




  <apex:pageBlockSection >
   <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!AccID}" title="data" >
       <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountSelectList}">

       </apex:selectOptions>
       <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" status="status" reRender="dt, table" action="{!Changemethod}"/>
    </apex:selectList> 
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  <apex:outputPanel id="dt"></apex:outputPanel>
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList }" var="c" id="table">

                  <apex:column >                   
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" />
                </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!c.con.lastname}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!c.con.email}"/>


    </apex:pageBlockTable>    
    <apex:commandButton value="SendMail" action="{!Changemethod}"/>

  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

My Controller class

```
public class WrapperAcccountWithEachContact {

public String AccID{Get;set;}
  public List<wrapper> contactList {get; set;} 
 public List<SelectOption> getAccountSelectList()
    {
        List<SelectOption> AccountSelectList =  new List<SelectOption>();
        AccountSelectList .add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));        
        for(Account acc : [select id , name from Account]){
          AccountSelectList .add(new SelectOption(acc.Id,acc.name));
        }
        return AccountSelectList ;
    }

    public pageReference Changemethod()
    {
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>lstmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage objMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    EmailTemplate temp = [select id from EmailTemplate where name='BirthdayWish Template'];


    system.debug('AccID:::::::::;;;'+AccID);
    contactList= new list<wrapper>();
    for(contact con: [select id , lastname,email from contact where AccountID =:AccID]){
        wrapper objWrap = new wrapper(con);
        system.debug('objWrap(((((((((((((((((((((((((('+objWrap );
        contactList.add(objWrap);
        if(objWrap.selected==true){
        system.debug('objWrap!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'+objWrap);

              objMail.setTemplateId(temp.id);
              objMail.setTargetObjectId(objWrap.con.id);
              objmail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
              lstMsg.add(objMail); 
            }

    }
    if(lstMsg!=null && lstMsg.size()>0)
        {
            Messaging.sendEmail(lstMsg);
        }

       return null; 

    }

    /*public pageReference sendMail(){
         List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>lstmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage objMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
         EmailTemplate temp = [select id from EmailTemplate where name='BirthdayWish Template'];
         for(WrapperClass wc:objWrap ){
            if(wc.isCheck==true){

              objMail.setTemplateId(temp.id);
              objMail.setTargetObjectId(wc.con.id);
              objmail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
              lstMsg.add(objMail); 
            }
        }
        if(lstMsg!=null && lstMsg.size()>0)
        {
            Messaging.sendEmail(lstMsg);
        }
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/ForgotPassword');
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }*/

    public class wrapper{
    public Contact con {get; set;}
     public Boolean selected {get; set;}

    public wrapper(Contact c) {         
            con = c;
            selected = false;
    }
    }




}
```

Mail is not going.. system.debug('objWrap!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'+objWrap); this debug line not working..

Answer (score 0):

The debug line is being skipped because your `objWrap.selected` is always false.  That is because in your `changeMethod()`, you are always requerying your contacts and instantiating a new `objwrap` list.  That wipes out any input submitted from the VF page.

What you need to do:

In your constructor, you need to retrieve the contacts and construct the list of wrapper items.  The pseudocode would be something like this:

```
public WrapperAcccountWithEachContact() {
    List<wrapper> contactList = new List<wrapper>();
    for (Contact con : [SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact]) {
        contactList.add(new wrapper(con));
    }
}
```

Then in the `changeMethod`, you simply loop through the wrapper list and create emails for the selected contacts.

```
public PageReference changeMethod() {
    for (wrapper con : contactList) {
        if (con.selected) {
            // add the email here
        }
    }
}
```